# Drone build and deploy

Tags: java, docker, drone.io

I'm setting up a pipeline for a java app. I can successfully build the app into a JAR, but I then want to create a docker container and add the JAR to that container.

My jar file is created at `/drone/src/target/app.jar`

However, when I try to ADD the jar during the container build stage, I get the following error...

```
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder947505275/app.jar: no such file or directory
```

How can I get my deploy stage to utilize the jar from the build stage?

Comment: Can you provide more details of your Dockerfile, and project structure?  The error message is telling you that the add is looking in a different directory than where your file is at.  Without knowing more info as to how you have defined the statement as well as other pre-steps in the docker file, it is not possible to help with a solution.

Comment: The step that fails from the Dockerfile is the following...  
ADD target/app.jar app.jar  
  
When I build the container manually, I am just copying my jar into the container. Obviously, I don't think I want to edit my Dockerfile to make it specific to this drone pipeline, so I suspect there should be some way to configure drone to know how to find the correct file.

Comment: Is your dockerfile in the src directory?

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately resolved the problem by changing my approach.

Instead of having drone package the JAR in step 1 and then have drone build a container which would have the JAR added to it, I updated my Dockerfile to do the packaging of the JAR. So the pipeline now just has 1 stage but it achieves what I set out to do.